# Import matlab with space and tab delimiter

Tags: matlab, file-import

I need to import a txt file into Matlab which has this format

```
text text text           
1           0 1 2 3
            4 5 6 7
2           10 11 15 18
            15 1 18 3
```

The first column is separated with the second one by a tab delimiter, while the rest of the data are separated by a space.
I tried to import it using this:

```
g = importdata('file.txt',delimiterIn,headerlinesIn);
delimiterIn = ' ';
headerlinesIn = 1;
```

but then the extracted table is like this:

```
text text text  
1 0 1 2 3
4 5 6 7 nan
2 10 11 15 18
15 1 18 3 nan
```

What I want is a table that maintains the format, with the first column of g.data on its own and then all the others.

I want an output matrix like

```
1 0 1 2 3
  4 5 6 7
2 10 11 15 18
  15 1 18 3
```

Then if I need to extract data represented by 2 in the first column, I can put it into another matrix with the values

```
10 11 15 18
15 1 18 3
```

each number inside a cell of a matrix

How can I do it?

Comment: not sure what you mean by "with the first column of g.data with just the first column and then all the others", why don't you give the desired output?

Comment: Done. I want that the first column (with values 1,2,...) and the rest of the data would be aligned. In this way I can extract from the first column the reference that I need to identify the rest of the data.
For example: I need to extract data represented by `2` -> I put into another matrix the values 
`10 11 15 18
  15 1 18 3`
each number inside a cell of a matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sollution might be:

```
fid = fopen('test.txt');
M = {[]};Midx=1;
l = fgetl(fid); %header
l = fgetl(fid);
while ~isnumeric(l)
    idx = str2double(l(1));
    if ~isnan(idx)
        Midx=idx;
        M{Midx}=[];
        l = l(2:end);
    end
    val = cell2mat(textscan(l,'%f'))';
    M{Midx}=[M{Midx};val];
    l=fgetl(fid);
end
fclose(fid);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit too pragmatic, but this might help:

```
for i=1:size(A,1)
  if isnan(A(i,end))==1
    A(i,2:end) = A(i,1:4);
    A(i,1) = NaN;
  end
end

for i=1:size(A,1)
  if A(i,1)==2
    B = A(i:i+1,2:end);
  end
end
```